# Is there any way to use sklearn on GPU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gpu, cuml

I am training model using a `VotingClassifier` in `sklearn`.
The dataset is large, approximately 1 millions tabular rows.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC

log_clf = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000)
rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
svm_clf = SVC()
voting_clf = VotingClassifier(
                estimators=[('lr', log_clf), ('rf', rnd_clf), ('svc', svm_clf)],
                voting='hard'
            )
```

I did some research and there are `cuML` available for `sklearn` to work on GPU.
But `cuml` doesn't support `VotingClassifier` yet.
Is there any other ways to train `sklearn` model on GPU at the moment?

```py
from cuml.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as cuRFC
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from cuml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from cuml.svm import LinearSVC
```

I tried to use voting classifier with `cuML` models.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Most cuML estimators can be used in scikit-learn's VotingClassifier. See this blog for an example: https://medium.com/rapids-ai/100x-faster-machine-learning-model-ensembling-with-rapids-cuml-and-scikit-learn-meta-estimators-d869788ee6b1    But, it appears there may be a bug when using cuML's RandomForestClassifier with scikit-learn's VotingClassifier. If you remove that model, things work.  Can you file an issue at https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/

Comment: I've actually found the root cause and filed a bug on cuML. It would be great if you could comment on the issue and indicate how much (or how little) it's impacting you. Thanks!  https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/5637

Comment: How did you try to use those models? What exactly didn't work? Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

By default it does not use GPU, especially if it is running inside Docker, unless you use nvidia-docker and an image with a built-in support. Scikit-learn is not intended to be used as a deep-learning framework and it does not provide any GPU support.